# AJAX: combining upload file and text input code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm using jQuery and Ajax for my forms to submit data and files but I'm not sure how to send both data and files in one form?

I have code like this:

```js
$("#save-sm").bind("click", function(event) {
  var url = "sm.input.php";

  var v_name_sm = $('input:text[name=name_sm]').val();

  // sending for process
  $.post(url, {name_sm: v_name_sm, id: id_sm} ,function() {

    // show data <div id="data-sm"></div>
    $("#data-sm").load(main);

    // hide modal dialog
    $('#dialog-sm').modal('hide');

  });
});
```

and I want add file upload script, like this one:

```js
$("form#data").submit(function(){

  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });

  return false;
});
```

how combining all code together so I can send both in once??

thanks :D

---

OK so, this is my final code:

```js
$("#save-sm").bind("click", function(event) {

  var v_name_sm = $('input:text[name=name_sm]').val();
  var id_sm = "your variable";
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form-sm"));
  formData.append("name_sn",v_name_sm);
  formData.append("id",id_sm);

  $.ajax({
    url: 'sm.input.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function () {
      // show data <div id="data-sm"></div>
      $("#data-sm").load(main);
      // hide modal dialog
      $('#dialog-sm').modal('hide');
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });

  return false;
});
```

Comment: Put the text box in the from and use the second piece of code.

Comment: so I dont need  jQuery $.post again?

Comment: When you use `new FormData(a_form);` all the fields in the from will be posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$("form#data").submit(function(){

  var v_name_sm = $('input:text[name=name_sm]').val();
  var id_sm = "your variable";
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
  formData.append("name_sn",v_name_sm);
  formData.append("id",id_sm);
  $.ajax({
    url: window.location.pathname,
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
  });

  return false;
});
```